# Commonly used array option in Objective-C

Tags: python, ios, objective-c, arrays

I am trying to convert my python code to an Objective-C code. What's the most commonly used among the developers in iOS or Objective-C world for lists of lists in case of **integer numbers** in python?

For example:
in **Python**: l = [[1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1]]
in **Objective-C**: NSArray* array [@[@1,@1,@1,@1],@[@1,@1,@1,@1]]
Is it the best way?

Other questions:

- What is the best way to access elements? (using objectAtIndex?)
- What is the best way to subtract a value from an element? (like in Python l[0][0]-1)

Comment: What do you mean by "subtract a value from an element? Do you mean (A) calculate a - b, where a comes from your array, and b is a constant? Or do you mean (B) fetch the value a from some location in the array, subtract a value from it, and put it back in the array?

Answer (score 2):

The way you are creating the array is correct. Remember that you are not entering integer numbers but instances of `NSNumbers`. Primitive types cannot be added to `NSArrays` or `NSDictionarys`, that is why you need the @ symbol. That is a short hand way of casting the value to a `NSNumber`.

You can access your elements similarly to python.

```
NSArray *array = @[@[@1, @2, @3], @[@4, @5, @6]];
NSNumber *one = array[0][0];
NSInteger *oneInt = [one integerValue]; // Integer representation of the first element of the first array.

NSArray *array = @[@[@1, @2, @3], @[@4, @5, @6]];
NSNumber *one = [[array objectForIndex:0] objectForIndex:0];
NSInteger *oneInt = [one integerValue]; // Integer representation of the first element of the first array.
```

Both of these are equivelent ways of accessing elements of an array. Which one you use is more of a personal preference. I prefer the shorter version.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is "It depends." Objective-C supports both C-style arrays (which are really just pointers into a memory buffer and some semantic sugar to handle the pointer math) or NSArrays, which are container objects that manage other objects. As @user7716368 said in their (very good) answer, you can't put integers into an `NSArray` directly. You have to create `NSNumber` objects, where are object wrappers for numeric values.

There are also 2 different flavors of NSArray in Objective-C, immutable and mutable arrays. An immutable array can't be changed once it's created. So if you wanted to subtract 6 from the value at index [1][2] in a nested array, you'd have to make all the arrays in your nested construct mutable arrays.

If you need statically defined arrays of integers, or arrays of arrays of integers, using C syntax is worth considering:

```
int intsArray[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
printf("array index 1 = %d\n", intsArray[1]);

int intsNestedArrays[2][4] = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 8}};
printf("intsNestedArrays[1,1] = %d\n", intsNestedArrays[1][1]);
```

Note that C style 2-dimensional arrays can't be "ragged" (where the 2nd' level arrays have differing numbers of entries.) They have to be a matrix. Objective-C NSArrays **can** be "ragged".

### Edit:

Note that Swift's arrays are much more sensible than Objective-C's. Arrays are objects, and Integers are objects, but perform almost as fast as C-style memory buffer arrays, and with lots of very powerful object-oriented and functional capabilities.

If you're just getting to arrays of integers in Objective-C, you should probably stop studying Objective-C and switch to Swift. Objective-C is on it's way out and Swift is where most people and organizations (me included) are putting their energies. I predict that in 5 years Objective-C will be all but dead on Apple platforms, and may not even be supported.

Answer (score 1):

> Q1. What is the best way to access elements? (using objectAtIndex?)
>
> Q2. What is the best way to subtract a value from an element? (like in Python
>   l[0][0]-1)

Ans1:
You can access by `array[0][1];` or `[[array objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:1];`
No best way, both is same.

Ans2:
Depends on your question requirement:
a) If you just want to calculate and store in another variable then:

```
int var = [array[0][1] intValue] - 2;
```

b) If you want to replace the value after deduction:
- You cannot use NSArray since this is fixed. You need to use NSMutableArray.
so assuming array is NSMutableArray, you can do:

```
array[0][1] =  @([array[0][1] intValue] - 2);
```